# How to configure .vimrc for Python code without .py filename extension?

Tags: python, vi

So, I'm pretty happy with my .vimrc config for Python - except I started leaving off the .py suffix for scripts and now vim has no idea that the file I'm editing is a Python file.

Clarification: I've confirmed that vim knows I'm editing a python file using
    :echo &filetype
which reports back 'python'.

So, the real question is how to assign python-specific behavior when I'm currently using file extensions for this purpose (see below).  Can that be driven with filetype?  Does one need both?

Regarding the lack of suffixes - my code is only intended for unix hosts, where this is commonplace, and I like hiding the implementation details so I could hypothetically change the implementation later.

Here's a fraction of my .vimrc:

```
au BufRead,BufNewFile *py,*pyw   set tabstop=4
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.py,*pyw  set shiftwidth=4
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.py,*.pyw set expandtab
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.py,*pyw  set softtabstop=4
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.py,*.pyw set textwidth=79
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to enable python-specific settings for files with no extension whatsoever, is to enable [filetype plugin](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/filetype.html) and, optionally, to teach Vim how Python file looks like.

Modify those files:

**$HOME/.vimrc**

Enable filetype plugin in Vim. This alllows to put language-specific settings into `$HOME/.vim/ftplugin/` directory. Those settings are based on file type, not file extension.

```
filetype plugin on
syntax on
```

**$HOME/.vim/scripts.vim**

Teach Vim how Python file looks like. In this example Vim treats file as a python script if it contains `python` string somewhere in its first line. You can easily adapt regular expression here to incorporate more advanced checks.

Please note that `did_filetype()` ensures, that files with .py extensions without `python` in the first line are still considered to be python scripts.

```
if did_filetype()
    finish
endif
if getline(1) =~ '.*python.*'
    setfiletype python
endif
```

**$HOME/.vim/ftplugin/python.vim**

Finally, put all the python-specific settings here:

```
setlocal tabstop=4
setlocal shiftwidth=4
setlocal expandtab
setlocal softtabstop=4
setlocal textwidth=79
```

---

**More info:**

Modyfing of `scripts.vim` is not necessary if file has some standard python header, on example `#!/usr/bin/python` or `#!/usr/bin/env python`.

This heuristic is being performed in `/usr/share/vim/vim73/scripts.vim` (your path may be different, depending on Vim version and install location).

Comment: Thank you - it doesn't address the problem at hand, but looks interesting.

Comment: No problem. I've expanded my answer with additional options - hope those help.

Comment: Thanks - it looks like I need option #1.  Can you show how that would look in a .vimrc file.   I *think* I've got to turn that detection on and then set various feature on using both filetype & file extension(?)

Comment: I'm surprised it isn't working for you by default. What's your Vim version? Is it compiled with python support? (see :version). If all else fails, you can always use option #2 with 'if getline(1) =~ '^#!/usr/bin/python$'' or similar.

Comment: BTW, for option #1 Vim's implementation of file type detection is in 'scripts.vim' located under /usr/share/vim (path may differ). My Vim installation detects file language by matching the first line of a file, so it's in fact option #2 we discussed.

Comment: :echo &filetype - shows the filetype is Python.  But my features are set based on file extension as I have in the original question.  What is the right way to set these features based on either filetype, file extension, or some combo?

Comment: Okay, I think I understand your problem now. I've updated the answer, hope it's what you were looking for.